# How to get doctrine datetime translated in Symfony2

Tags: php, date, datetime, symfony, internationalization

I'm trying to get a datetime object translated to Dutch within Symfony2. 
Can anyone tell me how to do this.

I already tried to strftime a date => no luck :(
I already tried to format the date => no luck either :(

Can anyone help on this?

If any extra info is needed, please let me know and I will add the info to this question.

---

I found another solution, which can be done without any extra bundles installed.

```
$formatter = new \IntlDateFormatter(\Locale::getDefault(), \IntlDateFormatter::NONE, \IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
//http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime for date formats
$formatter->setPattern("EEEE d MMMM Y");
$page['modify_date'] = $formatter->format($page['modify_date']);
$page['create_date'] = $formatter->format($page['create_date']);
```

Where $formatter->format(DATE), formats the date with the right pattern. 
This can be done from the controller.

The date can by printed from twig as follows: {{modify_date}}

Answer (score 1):

You could use/have a look at the [KNPTimeBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpTimeBundle) to see how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

With [SonataIntlBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataIntlBundle) you can do:

```
{{ date_time_object | format_date }} => '1 févr. 2011'
{{ date_time_object | format_time }} => '19:55:26'
{{ date_time_object | format_datetime }} => '1 févr. 2011 19:55:26'
```

You can pass a locale parameter of course. [Check docs](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataIntlBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/reference/datetime.rst)